# size of uint8, uint16 and uint32?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am working with code that uses types like `uint8` (1 byte wide unsigned integer), `uint16` (2 byte wide unsigned integer), `uint32` (4 byte wide unsigned integer), etc..

My questions are:

- Are `uint8` and `char` the same size?
- Are `uint16` and `int` the same size?
- Are `uint32` and `long` the same size?
- Are `uint64` and `double` the same size?

for example:

```
uint8 c[20];
```

Shouldn't the size of this be 20?

I wrote some code in visual studio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef unsigned int uint32;
typedef unsigned int uint8;

int main()
{
    double a = 1320.134;
    uint32 b;
    uint8 c[20];
    b = (unsigned int)a;
    c[3] = b;
    printf("value is %d", c[3]);
    return 1;
}
```

but the size of `c` in debug mode is 50. Why is that?

Comment: should be `typedef unsigned char uint8;`, use uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t in <stdint.h>.

Comment: `sizeof c` is 50?  It should be `20 * sizeof(unsigned int)` which cannot be 50.

Comment: how to convert the int to char to get the final solution in char ??

Comment: The code example contradicts the earlier text: it contains `typedef unsigned int uint32` and `typedef unsigned int uint8`, which is very confusing. Please clarify.

Comment: Please clarify "the size of c in debug mode is 50". Is 50 supposed to be a hexadecimal number (i.e. 80 decimal)? Also, is it related in any way to the code?

Answer (score 27):

`uint8`, `uint16`, `uint32`, and `uint64` are probably Microsoft-specific types.

As of the 1999 standard, C supports standard typedefs with similar meanings, defined in `<stdint.h>`: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, and `uint64_t`. I'll assume that the Microsoft-specific types are defined similarly. Microsoft does support `<stdint.h>`, at least as of Visual Studio 2010, but older code may use `uint8` et al.

The predefined types `char`, `short`, `int` et al have sizes that vary from one C implementation to another. The C standard has certain minimum requirements (`char` is *at least* 8 bits, `short` and `int` are at least 16, `long` is at least 32, and each type in that list is at least as wide as the previous type), but permits some flexibility. For example, I've seen systems where `int` is 16, 32, or 64 bits.

`char` is *almost* always exactly 8 bits, but it's permitted to be wider. And plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned.

`uint8_t` is required to be an unsigned integer type that's exactly 8 bits wide. It's likely to be a typedef for `unsigned char`, though it might be a typedef for plain `char` if plain `char` happens to be unsigned. If there is no predefined 8-bit unsigned type, then `uint8_t` will not be defined at all.

Similarly, each `uintN_t` type is an unsigned type that's exactly N bits wide.

In addition, `<stdint.h>` defines corresponding signed `intN_t` types, as well as `int_fastN_t` and `int_leastN_t` types that are *at least* the specified width.

The `[u]intN_t` types are guaranteed to have no padding bits, so the size of each is exactly N bits. The signed `intN_t` types are required to use a 2's-complement representation.

Although `uint32_t` might be the same as `unsigned int`, for example, you shouldn't *assume* that.  Use `unsigned int` when you need an unsigned integer type that's at least 16 bits wide, and that's the "natural" size for the current system. Use `uint32_t` when you need an unsigned integer type that's exactly 32 bits wide.

(And no, `uint64` or `uint64_t` is not the same as `double`; `double` is a floating-point type.)

Comment: you should probably write the size of each type in your answer

Comment: @RitzyDev "Similarly, each `uintN_t` type is an unsigned type that's exactly N bits wide." Was that not clear enough?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean the size I mean the max value, e.g 8 = 255, etc,  I guess it doesn't pertain to this question as much but, google directed me here when trying to get the max value for some reason

Answer (score 3):

It's quite unclear how you are computing the size ("the size in debug mode"?").

Use `printf()`:

```
printf("the size of c is %u\n", (unsigned int) sizeof c);
```

Normally you'd print a `size_t` value (which is the type `sizeof` returns) with `%zu`, but if you're using a pre-C99 compiler like Visual Studio that won't work.

You need to find the `typedef` statements in your code that define the custom names like `uint8` and so on; those are not standard so nobody here can know how they're defined *in your code*.

New C code should use `<stdint.h>` which gives you `uint8_t` and so on.

Comment: To get the value of c then what should i do ?? finally I want to store the value in the c[3];